# scrapy stopped abruptly with out any error messages

Tags: python, scrapy

Python Scrapy: I am trying to scrape big web site through their api. It has around 100 main urls and it will come with sub urls. My code parsed around a million in 4 hours and stopped with out any error message.  I am running in 11 threads in one process.

Comment: Can you share the scrapy logs ?

Comment: It was memory issue. So i planned to use redis queue instead of using global variable. but i could nt yield the item back to redis queue.